# Euler gamma function differential

Tags: calculus, gamma-function

Do you have any piece of advice on how to calculate a differential of an Euler Gamma function for $ x \in R- Z $?Thank you for all your answers.

Comment: You mean $\Gamma(x)$?  Write the definition using an integral, then differentiate under the integral sign to get $\Gamma'(x)$, also written as an integral.

Comment: It may be useful to rewrite $\Gamma'(x)$ as $\;\Gamma'(x)=\psi(x)\Gamma(x)\;$ from the definition and the properties of the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\Gamma(x)$ is a convex function of $x$,
$$
\scriptsize\overbrace{\frac{\log(\Gamma(x+n))-\log(\Gamma(x+n-1))}{(x+n)-(x+n-1)}}^{\log(x+n-1)}
\le\overbrace{\frac{\Gamma'(x+n)}{\Gamma(x+n)}}^{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\log(\Gamma(x+n))}
\le\overbrace{\frac{\log(\Gamma(x+n+1))-\log(\Gamma(x+n))}{(x+n+1)-(x+n)}}^{\log(x+n)}\tag{1}
$$
Thus, for a fixed $x$, $(1)$ says
$$
\frac{\Gamma'(x+n)}{\Gamma(x+n)}=\log(n)+O\!\left(\frac1n\right)\tag{2}
$$
The recursion for $\Gamma(x)$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
\Gamma(x+n)&=(x+n-1)(x+n-2)\cdots x\,\Gamma(x)\tag{3}\\[6pt]
\log(\Gamma(x+n))&=\log(x+n-1)+\log(x+n-2)+\cdots+\log(x)+\log(\Gamma(x))\tag{4}\\
\frac{\Gamma'(x+n)}{\Gamma(x+n)}&=\frac1{x+n-1}+\frac1{x+n-2}+\cdots+\frac1x+\frac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)}\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
Rewriting $(5)$ and applying $(2)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)}
&=\frac{\Gamma'(x+n)}{\Gamma(x+n)}-\left(\frac1x+\frac1{x+1}+\cdots+\frac1{x+n-1}\right)\tag{6}\\
&=\log(n)+O\!\left(\frac1n\right)-\left(\frac11+\frac12+\cdots+\frac1n\right)\tag{7}\\
&+\left(\frac11+\frac12+\cdots+\frac1n\right)-\left(\frac1x+\frac1{x+1}+\cdots+\frac1{x+n-1}\right)\tag{8}\\
&=-\gamma+O\!\left(\frac1n\right)+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac1{k+1}-\frac1{k+x}\right)\tag{9}\\
&=-\gamma+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac1{k+1}-\frac1{k+x}\right)\tag{10}
\end{align}
$$