# What's $x^n = n!$ approximately

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

What is the approximate solution to:

$x ^{1000} = 1000 !$

How can you solve for x?

More generally, for some constant $k$, how can you solve:

$x^k = k!$

Comment: As $1000!$ has many, many prime factors, it is impossible to get the exact number without getting too large. But there might be approximate solutions.

Comment: When we approximate $\sum_{k=1}^n\ln k$ with $\int_1^k\ln x\,dx$ we get the approximate formula $\ln (k!)\approx k\ln k-k$. Therefore
$$\ln x=\ln \root k\of{k!}\approx\frac1k(k\ln k-k)=\ln k-1.$$
So $x\approx k/e$. With $k=1000$ we have $1000/e\approx 367.88$. The exact solution would be $x\approx369.49$. Expect approximation error in that ballpark.

Comment: The upper limit of my intergal should be $n$ rather than $k$. Or, possible better, the summation should be $\sum_{i=1}^k\ln i$. Too late to edit. Sorry.

Comment: First of all , $\sqrt[k]{k!}$ is the exact solution. For large $k$ , we can use Stirling as mentioned but we can also just multiply the $k$-th roots of the numbers from $1$ to $k$. The solution is irrational for every $k\ge 2$, so rounding is inevitable anyway, if we want to determine the decimal expansion.

Comment: If $k$ is too large to calculate the product , or if you do not have a table calculator that can handle loops , or the computation would be too time consuming, then we must be content with the Stirling approximation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) when $n \rightarrow +\infty$:
$$\ln(n!) = n\ln(n)-n+O(\ln(n))$$

So,
\begin{align}
x^k = k! & \Leftrightarrow  k\ln(x) =\ln(k!) \\
& \Leftrightarrow  k\ln(x) =k\ln(k)-k+O(\ln(k)) \\
& \Leftrightarrow  \ln(x) =\ln(k)-1+O(\frac{\ln(k)}{k}) \\
& \Leftrightarrow  \ln(x) =\ln(k)-1+O(\frac{\ln(k)}{k}) \\
& \Leftrightarrow  x =\frac{k}{e} \times\exp{(O(\frac{\ln(k)}{k}))} \approx \frac{k}{e}\\
\end{align}

Comment: I like this approach!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that by the Hierarchy of limits, $\frac{x^n}{n!}\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, so $n$ would have to be 'quite small'. In response to your first problem, $1000\log{x}=log{1000!}$ so $\log{x}=\frac{log{1000!}}{1000}$. Can you see a way to complete the problem? If not, here is a hint:

What can you deduce about the function $f(x)=\frac{log{x!}}{x}$? Can you sketch a graph of it? How does its derivative compare with $\log{x}$? You should be able to use these to find an approximate intersection point.

[To differentiate ${\log{x!}}$, consider the Gamma function definition of factorials, then apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to differentiate.]

Comment: How would you differentiate your function $f$?   What does $x!$ mean for noninteger $x$?

Comment: Yes.  That might be worth including.

Comment: We can use the gamma function for factorials I believe - then use Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to differentiate

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out Randall - I'll include this now:)

Comment: I ask because differentiating the gamma function is highly nontrivial.

Comment: I agree it's not exactly standard but the formula for the $n$th derivative is relatively straightforward so could be memorised.

Comment: I don’t know any nice formulation of its derivative:   https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1634781/464495